# Training developers on new API features

Tags: language-agnostic

We have a new feature in our API that is used by internal developers that is significantly different than the typical MVC features of our platform.

What do others do in terms of training developers on these features.   Part of the information distribution will be done at a presentation but I was thinking of developing 1 or 2 worksheets that the developers could take away, work on and get some hands on experience in this portion of the API since it might be awhile until they use the new features.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about [Coding Dojo](http://codingdojo.org/cgi-bin/wiki.pl?WhatIsCodingDojo)?

Comment: Thanks for this link Fernando.  I'm going to see if i can implement something similar for a future lab type setting.

Answer (score 0):

assuming that you can't develop the feature in a way that prevents or at least warns on misuse.

have examples of usage of your new features. use these in your presentation.
make the examples available to everyone - via the means most appropriate to your organisation. also add links/reference to the examples from the documentation of the class.
if possible, examples should be from where the feature is really used. this removes the need to create additional examples that are not maintained with the live codebase.

Comment: Sounds good - i can make sure to hit these topics.